# How can i get Transaction list of an Address of ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

devs?

Does anybody know how can I get the list of transactions from addresses in the Ethereum blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

The Indexer allows to explore transactions by Ethereum address and obtain a history of any user|wallet in just a move, like Etherscan does

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't make it via JSON-RPC method.

But you can get the transaction history list by other API like Alchemy.

Here's what I found:

`https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/alchemy-getassettransfers`

here's an example result:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "result": {
    "transfers": [
      {
        "blockNum": "0xfc9d8a",
        "uniqueId": "0xd475145f3710a980744728994c1e6473c9cf482ade6fee51863bcae4e8a43359:external",
        "hash": "0xd475145f3710a980744728994c1e6473c9cf482ade6fee51863bcae4e8a43359",
        "from": "0x10ae09ed30a4029a673f24483fa7c8781a455e84",
        "to": "0x283af0b28c62c092c9727f1ee09c02ca627eb7f5",
        "value": 0.006626916447435505,
        "erc721TokenId": null,
        "erc1155Metadata": null,
        "tokenId": null,
        "asset": "ETH",
        "category": "external",
        "rawContract": {
          "value": "0x178b2538ce3af1",
          "address": null,
          "decimal": "0x12"
        }
      },
      {
        "blockNum": "0xfc22ad",
        "uniqueId": "0x63981ffc14e156d0585d2b25a83570e8715f2478c75f457e358098e9781467d9:external",
        "hash": "0x63981ffc14e156d0585d2b25a83570e8715f2478c75f457e358098e9781467d9",
        "from": "0x10ae09ed30a4029a673f24483fa7c8781a455e84",
        "to": "0xd95a1969c41112cee9a2c931e849bcef36a16f4c",
        "value": 0.0034,
        "erc721TokenId": null,
        "erc1155Metadata": null,
        "tokenId": null,
        "asset": "ETH",
        "category": "external",
        "rawContract": {
          "value": "0xc1448303c8000",
          "address": null,
          "decimal": "0x12"
        }
      }
    ],
    "pageKey": "c06bf4fc-00c6-4c3c-aba7-b0e0bede4342"
  }
}
```